# Exclude folders from "Open Folder" but not from left sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a method? I want to hide all dot folders from the "Open Folder" dropdown selection but not from the left sidebar since I need to see those when working on a project.

Tryed excluding all folders starting with dot but they disappeared also from left sidebar.